# Meteor function define across all .js project files

Tags: javascript, meteor

Say I have a function that returns a specific id of a player in a client side java-script file:

```
var playerId = function () {
    return Player.findOne({current:true})._id;
};
```

However as the project has grown, I have started to break up my code into a variety of .js files (player.js, game.js, round.js, etc).The problem arises when I want to reuse the function. I cannot call the playerId() function from a different .js file. As of right now I am just copying and pasting the function into every .js file that utilizes it. Is there a place I can define the function so that it is available to every .js file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is simply to remove the var in the declaration statement of the variable you wish to export.
http://docs.meteor.com/#namespacing

Also, make sure the load order is correct by following these rules : http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function by using the name of its .js in another file

Ex:

player.js

```
var player = {
 init: function() {
       player.playerId();
 },
 playerId : function () {
        return Player.findOne({current:true})._id;
 }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
        player.init();
});
```

game.js

```
game: function(){
      var p = player.playerId()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides giving the obvious tip of fixing your file dependencies, the best suggestion I can give is to use an excellent library called [Require JS](http://requirejs.org/). This will not only automatically take care of file dependency order and downloads, but it will also keep your global-scope clean of these type of utility functions. Require will also force you into better programming habits, which is why I advocate learning/using require to solve your issue.

Comment: Require JS is not applicable to Meteor AFAIK, because Meteor loads files in a different manner